# Call file php by ajax to download a file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have one PHP file and other JavaScript. In JavaScript, I pass the variable with location of place where the file exists but on the PHP side doesn't recognize and doesn't properly download the file.

Code of JavaScript:

```
var nameFile = oEvent.getParameters().listItem.getTitle();
var directory = "C:/xampp/htdocsui5launchpad/WebContent/documents/";

window.location =directory;

$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/ui5launchpad/WebContent/php/downloadPDF.php',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: "json",
            data: { album: nameFile },
            success: function (response, data, xhr) {
                window.location = 'http://localhost/ui5launchpad/WebContent/php/downloadPDF.php';

            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log("Error in PHP, downloadPDF.php ");
            }
        });
```

PHP code:

```
    if(isset($_POST["album"])){
        $name = $_POST["album"];
    }

    $dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/ui5launchpad/WebContent/documents/";

    $file = $dir . $name;

    if( isset($file)) {
        //echo $file;

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            //echo $file;
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }

    }
```

Can you help me, please ?

Thanks

Comment: you can not download a file using AJAX, you need to call that URL directly into the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Pandhi Bhaumik: 
I think you're wrong. Because if I have the url in php and call only php without parameters this work perfectly. My problem is when I pass the name

Comment: Maybe your SAPUI5 is doing GET rather than POST. Change `$_POST["album"]` to `$_REQUEST["album"]` or  `$_GET["album"]` and see what happens.

Comment: Found it. Why after success of an ajax to a url are you redirecting to the same url? There's your problem. In the end `window.location = 'http://localhost/ui5launchpad/WebContent/php/downloadPDF.php';` is what is returning the file to where you can see it, and NOT the ajax call.  But there's no parameter for the filename with your window.location code there. That's why its only working when you hardcode the filename. You can drop the ajax altogether and just do `window.location = 'http://localhost/ui5launchpad/WebContent/php/downloadPDF.php?album=' + nameFile;`

Comment: Not only that, but you had the totally unnecessary ajax code trying to download `datatype: "json",` when your php script its calling returns a PDF as `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: No one of this Suggestions works in my code. :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ajax to download a file. Just link the file direct to the browser.

In the link tag put the attribute like this:

`<a href="http://example.com/file.pdf" download>Download</a>`

Comment: But I'm not use HTML code.
I'm using SAPUI5 code where I have a list with files, and when de user select the file it's supposed to do the download through javascript.

Comment: Whats the option to call a link directly in the SAPUI5?

Comment: We have a link option. But my list is only filled as text, so I only have access for the name of the file .